# How to set warning in g++ for warning of returning pointer to local variable?

Tags: c++, g++, warnings

I think both of the two functions are problematic because they return reference/pointer to local variable allocated in stack:

```
int &func1() {
   int a = 3; 
   return a;
}
int *func2() {
    int a = 3;
    int *p = &a;
    return p;
}
```

but when I use compile command g++ -Wall, why it only gives warning for func1 but not func2? Is it because func2 could be intentionally used for some purpose or the warning could be set by adding other parameter? My g++ version is 4.6.3, on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Returning a reference to a local variable is undefined behaviour. Returning some pointer is not. Only *dereferencing* the pointer is. It's true that there is no way to use the value of `func2()` sensibly, but it's not undefined behaviour just there and then.

Comment: Duplicate ?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228731/

Comment: On http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html, there is an option (`-Wno-return-local-addr`) that (if I understand correctly) is suposed to **remove** this kind of warning, i.e., the warning is enabled by default. Maybe upgrade gcc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for the compiler to know what you are trying to do with the pointer you are returning in **func2**.

You could as well be returning an instance for an array, for example:

```
int *func2() {
    int a = 3;
    int *p = &a;
    /*some useful stuff*/
    if (some_criteria)
        p = new int[10];
    return p;
}
```

Because the compiler does not have the power to evaluate the semantics of the returned pointer.

Comment: Very good example, didn't think about that ! So, yes, my comment above is irrelevant...

Answer (score 0):

Per @kebs above  gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html, there is an option (-Wno-return-local-addr) that sort of does this, enabled by default with -Wall (I checked).

However, I had something like

```
    char * foo(string bar) {
      return bar.c_str();
    }
```

No warning.  But bar is a copy so a local value that is silently returned despite -Wall.

Should have had extr &

```
    char * foo(string &bar) {
      return bar.c_str();
    }
```

Wasted hours tracking that down in a large program that almost always worked correctly.